# AWS s3 find the best server for downloading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to download some files on s3 bucket region TOKYO. But sometimes the download is not consistent. Sometimes Sydney is faster than Tokyo or Singapore is faster than Sydney.

If I use AWS cloudfront for s3. Can this improve my downloading speed?? **Im using the AWS CLI sync command to download some stuff**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cloudfront will distribute files from the closest endpoint to the user. Its also a bit more optimized for delivery than S3 is.

However, if you are using the cli command, then you will always connect directly to s3 and not via cloudfront endpoints.

Comment: If you set up a cloudfront distribution and download directly via that endpoint, then it will work. But the cli will always connect directly to the s3 endpoint.

Comment: Ok.. got it.. Thanks.. :)